# Plotting positive function ... looks like it goes negative

Tags: plotting

I recently answered a question on the stats SE site which involved a $\text{Sinc}^2$ distribution with pdf:

```
f = (Sin[x]^2)/(Pi x^2)
```

... defined on the real line. Plotting it with code such as:

```
Plot[f, {x, -15, 15}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "f"}]
```

yields:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/mrscincsquaredpdf.png))</sub>

Another user commented that the plot seems to have a visual aberration ... it *appears* as though the pdf becomes negative each time it hits the $x$-axis (which it cannot actually do). Perhaps this is because the plotted curve is thicker than $x$-axis curve --- using `PlotStyle -> Thin` seems to alleviate the problem. On the other hand, the problem becomes worse if I generate the picture, and then re-size it to be smaller, or use say `ImageSize -> 300`.

I am wondering to what extent this is a visual aberration or a Mma plotting aberration? Is Mma actually plotting the curve below the axis - because that is how it appears?

Comment: It's visual - a combination of the interpolation and thickness of the line. When I have a plot where this artifact happens and it bugs me, I just add an appropriately tiny y offset to the function.

Comment: Does `AxesStyle -> Thick` satisfy you?

Comment: Go with `Frame->True`

Comment: I am using MMA 10.4.0 on Win7-64, and my system produces a graph that just seems to be touching the horizontal axis, rather than going past it towards negative values ([example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bTOcP.png)). Perhaps this behavior is version / OS / graphics dependent.

Comment: I am also not seeing this behavior on Win7-64 with MMa 10.4.1. BTW is there a reason for not using something like `Sinc2Distribution = ProbabilityDistribution[ f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]` and then using `PDF[Sinc2Distribution][x]` within the `Plot`?

Comment: @gwr I would take care using black name boxes to describe desired functional forms, as there are often multiple competing parameterisations or forms for standard statistical distributions, and unless you specifically manually check each time, it is very easy to make blunders. My preferred approach is to work with the exact functional form of interest: WYSIWYG. Interesting that the visual artefact may be just a Mac problem?

Comment: Can't follow the argument as `ProbabilityDistribution` does use the explicitly given definition for the density? But I agree with the predefined distributions as some are having odd parametrizations. Nevertheless I like to use the general `ProbabilityDistribution` as it lets you enter the neat statistics framework for distributions. (Nice for Bayes especially...)

Answer (score 2):

If I force the axes to cross at the origin with `AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}`, I see only the expected tangencies:

```
Plot[Sinc[x]^2/π, {x, -15, 15}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: And also  all should be double real roots.